# Combining two sentence in one while ensuring grammar errors are not present

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Since English is my second language, I have been trying to wrap my head around the subheading I am writing.

I feel like it would be better written if it was divided into multiple sentence, but I was hoping that the following sentence communicates well enough so i don't have to break it up and further elaborate.

> NAME is a community that helps each other code better by rating each
>   other's efforts and helps managers pair with other fellow developers

Could anyone confirms that the above sentence makes grammatical sentence or would I need to break it up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would replace the first *each other* with *its members* or something similar, since *each other* usually refers back to plural antecedents.

Comment: I think presenting these two statements in a single sentence is stylistically poor. What you've got is essentially *X helps A [do something] **and** [X] helps B [do something else]*. Which would be nicely "balanced" if A and B were "comparable, juxtaposable" elements of the same general syntactic/semantic type, but with **A = each other** and **B = managers** it really jars for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Based on your suggestions, How about "NAME is a community that helps its members code better by rating each other's efforts. It also helps managers pair with other fellow developers"

Comment: Pairing _managers_ with _other fellow developers_ sounds really strange. Managers are not developers, so they have no _fellow_ developers. _other_ also implies that managers are developers. It's like you're trying to match zebra's with other fellow lions.